# Qemu vm crashed with message 'Terminating on signal 1'

Tags: linux, qemu

I have a qemu vm that shutdown for some reason. The only log I have on qemu is:

> qemu: terminating on signal 1 from pid xxxxx

Do you know what signal 1 is ?

Comment: Read this: [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Note the "Search, and research" part.

Comment: I already have searched. I could only finds reasons for signal **15**

Comment: https://lists.xenproject.org/archives/html/xen-users/2014-03/msg00162.html and https://github.com/hyperhq/hyperd/issues/31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

man 7 signal:

```
  SIGHUP        1       Term    Hangup detected on controlling terminal
                                 or death of controlling process
```

Perhaps the terminal was closed, the session logged out or something like that.

Comment: Qemu would of died ? but my other vm should of died too. no ?

Comment: Depends, how are you launching them? (also who is pid xxxxx, and why is it sending signals?). Anyway, if you want to make a process immune to session hangup, run it inside nohup or screen.

Comment: I use virt-manager. Good question I don't know, I thought it was the pid of the vm itself but anyway it doesn't exist anymore. Any idea what a pid was used for ?

Comment: another followup question: did anything notable happen at the time of the signal? (user logout? daily cron run?)

Comment: Yep a user logout after an ansible playbook execution, nothing that would turn off a vm nor any logs that go that way. No cron.

Comment: I wonder if this is systemd killing all processes of a user after that user has logged out, see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=825394